# Can't Use PageMethod (ajax in C# .net)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I try to use PageMethod in asp.net.
First I add script Manager to my aspx page:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

I wrote onClick method on JS:

```
   function TryAJAX() {
            PageMethods.TryA( onSucess, onError);

            function onSucess(result) {
                alert('good.');           
            }

            function onError(result) {
                alert('Something wrong.');
            }
        }
```

and in the code behind:

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static String TryA()
    {
        return "JSON CHECK";

    }
```

and I always get the message 'something wrong' . althouth that in debugger I see it's enter to the methood 'TryA'.

What is the problem? 
thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not the exact path you were looking to take for a solution, but I think it is a WAY better option, so here's my 2 cents...

your button in html

```
<input type="button" id="myStupidButton" value="Click Me Yo" />
```

you javascript- I am going to use jQuery too , if that is really a problem I can give you a pure js option:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '#myStupidButton', function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Mypage.aspx/TryA",
        success: function(data){
           // parse asp.net's response
           data = $.parseJson(data);
           //asp.net wraps all json into json like this   "d" : "yourresponse"
           alert(data.d);
        }
    });
});
```